# Redis cache and overall process

Tags: sql-server, database, caching, redis

I am having trouble understanding the start to finish call process of an application using redis as a cache. Say an application has a DB such as SQL and is using redis to cache how does the timing of that process work? To my understanding redis makes a call to the SQL DB to cache data and the UI calls and consumes that data directly from redis therefore limiting the calls to the SQL DB. Typically when does redis make the call to the DB to get its data? and how does it keep it in sync with the SQL DB? I am just trying to understand this high level. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Redis is just a cache, it provides a high-speed data store, whereas a database is slower but more reliable and with more features. Your application is responsible for getting data from Redis, and if it doesn't find it, pulling it from the database and adding it to Redis, with appropriate expiration and invalidation mechanics.

Comment: How many instances of redis are usually required to handle a large application?

Comment: "How long is a piece of string?" I don't have nearly enough information to even begin to answer that, and it's not a question for SO. It depends on what "large" application means, what it does, with how much data, how often, and what resources are available to the redis instances.

Answer (score 1):

Let's walk through a simplified example.  Let's consider a hypothetical application in Python that uses Redis to cache a user object.  The user objects are cached in Redis under the key `user:{id}` in a Hash datatype.  The system of record for the user data is stored in a relational database. Id is an integer, pk generated in the db.

To fetch a user we would execute code something like this:

```
# r = redis.StrictRedis(hostname)
def get_user(r, id):
    key = "user:{}".format(id)
    user = r.hgetall(key)
    if user is None:
        return fetch_user_from_db(id)
    else:
        return user
```

To write a user we would execute code similar to:

```
# r = redis.StrictRedis(hostname)
def update_user(r, user):
    key = "user:{}".format(user['id'])
    r.delete(key)
    write_user_to_db(user)
```

This simplified example leaves out many of the details of keeping your cache and db consistency in a distributed environment, but for a single node this is the basic process.  Your app has to handle the details of caching, checking for a cache hit and invalidating on write.

Answer (score 0):

I myself have never come across a scenario where Redis calls a SQL DB. Since Redis is a key-value store that keeps its own data in RAM, it's usually used directly for caching by apps. There's no involvement of the SQL DB at all in these cases.

The greatest strength of Redis is that many operations return data in constant time, independent on how many elements are stored. This is why it's great for many use cases like caching and locking mechanisms that need very quick response times.